# python string split based on "\"

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have to explode the following string based on `"\"`. The probelm is, `string.split('\')` does not work and the `re.split("\/",text)`.
I have no idea.

the string is simple

```
D123D\user.name
```

the first part is sometimes longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *escape* the backslash in a Python string literal:

```
string.split('\\')
```

Demo:

```
>>> r'D123D\user.name'.split('\\')
['D123D', 'user.name']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
re.split(r"\",text)
```

should work as well

Comment: Raw strings with trailing odd number of backslashes do not work. See [Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)